# Highchart chart not work on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts, jquery-events

I have created Highchart for my report, but its not appear on chrome and Firefox browser, but  appear on IE, when I allow to ActiveX in IE after that chart appear correctly. Please can anyone give me a reason for that?

Comment: please make a fiddle verysoon

Comment: Highcharts does works on those browsers. Your problem isn't there. Plus, you should post some code. You tagged a lot of things but I don't see any line of code in your question.

Comment: there are not any error in code becase i have did check its on dreamwever and on http://jsfiddle.net/ code is work correctly

Comment: If it is so, where is the fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess here, but I've seen Chrome browsers not display HighCharts in a page loaded via SSL when you use the CDN hosted scripts.  Check to see if there is a grey shield icon in the address bar.  Click that and select "Load unsafe script".

A fix to this is to include the HighCharts script on your own server, over ssl (https://)

it's also recommended that you use Highcharts CDN without a protocol, and the browser will pick whichever one it needs.
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanx its a rason for that. because highchart work on chrome after upload to server. thanx buddy

Comment: turned out to be a pretty nice question somehow.